# xtable into RStudio in order to get Latex table format

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I'm doing a LaTex document using RStudio in Windows 7 by using knitr. I've have some problems such as:

- When I use xtable() for these data frames , I just can get the code for Latex, is it possible to get directly the Latex format of tables in my pdf?

Comment: See if https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr can help you. Possibly also the SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166758/xtable-in-rmd-then-knit-as-pdf-in-rstudio-shows-comments